# Is there any way to create a reports to see all members involvement like a roadmap of a project in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

We want to see all my team members' involvements or freeness in a single sheet. The fact is that there are multiple projects, features, and tasks. A team member can have different tasks from different projects. We do not need any detailed task breakdown. We just think if there is any way to see a report like the following: For example, let's say John Doe has tasks assigned from 1-4 January and then he has some other task from 8-10 January, So that I can see that John Doe is free from 5-7 January and I can add him into some other projects.

```
Date range: 01 January to 31 January

--------------------------------------------------------------------
Team Member | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | ...
--------------------------------------------------------------------
John Doe    |===============|           |============|
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Martin                  |===================|
--------------------------------------------------------------------
James       |=========|         |==========|         |=============
```

and so on.

Any suggestion is highly appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there is no such report. In the Task work item, we only have Remaining Work field.
At the planning stage, Remaining Work corresponds to an estimate of how long it will take to complete the task. So we can only see how many hours a task will take, but can not see the date range for a task.

You could [set capacity for your team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/sprints/set-capacity?view=azure-devops), so that you can check whether any team member is under, at, or over capacity. Or, if someone hasn't even been assigned any work. Use the capacity bars to make these determinations.

[image]

More details of planning and working a sprint, you could get start from the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/sprints/assign-work-sprint?view=azure-devops

Comment: I want to dive deep into features from the task so that I could get the date range for a task from a feature. Your answer is a good approach, but I need the solution otherwise I may need to create one to solve this issue.

Comment: With your features defined, you're able to add multiple child items to them.  The child items may assign to different users. You may try to add "start" and "target" date fields by customizing the Tasks work item. In this way, you can query the date easily.

Comment: Is my reply helpful?